# ESP32-Cam: SD and camera use up all the pins

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32, gpio

All I need to do is take a photo and save it to the SD card when a button is pressed. But by using just the camera and SD card all the GPIO pins are used up. Is there a way of freeing one up for the button?

SD: GPIOs 2, 4, 12, 13, 14, 15

Camera: GPIO 0

Serial: GPIOs 1, 3

That only leaves GPIO 16 which seems to be High all the time.

```cpp
#include "esp_camera.h"
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "FS.h"                
#include "SD_MMC.h"            

#define BTN 16
#define LED_BUILT_IN 33

int picCount = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  pinMode(BTN, INPUT);
  pinMode(LED_BUILT_IN, OUTPUT);

  setupSD();
  setupCamera();
}

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(BTN) == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILT_IN, HIGH);
    takePicture();
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILT_IN, LOW);
  }
  delay(50);
}
```

Comment: esp-32 has many io. what board exactly do you use?

Comment: The typical [ESP32-Cam](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-cam-video-streaming-face-recognition-arduino-ide/#:~:text=The%20ESP32%2DCAM%20is%20a,files%20to%20serve%20to%20clients.)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to add one button and an I2C OLED display to ESP32 Cam to make a time lapse camera with a user interface.

I assigned the pins this way:

I 'borrowed' these

P2-1 / GPIO4  - I2C data

P2-5 / GPIO13 - I2C clock

P2-6 / GPIO12 - button

These are already used in the original design like so:

P2-1 / GPIO4 is used for the flash LED - I disconnected the LED because I didn't need it. You could leave it connected - it will flash annoyingly when the display is being updated but can also still be lit constantly if required as you probably won;t be updating the display while illuminating for a photo.
This pin is also used for the SD card in the original design which used six wires to access the SD card. I changed it instead to use only three thus freeing up these pins.

For the SD card I used 3 wire mode which uses:

P2-2 / GPIO2   - SD card MISO / data 0

P2-3 / GPIO14  - SD card clock

P2-4 / GPIO 15 - SD card MOSI / Command

These are already internally connected in the ESP32Cam board. The pins mentioned above (GPIO4, GPIO13 and GPIO12) are also conencted to the SD card but cause no harm if the SD card is being used in three wire mode.

You could also use the UART 0 TX and RX pins for other functions which you would disconnect when you want to program the device and then reconnect after you have programmed it.

P1-2 / GPIO1  - UART TX

P1-3 / GPIO3  - UART RX

If you use them for a button you don't need a means of isolating them when programming but make sure to put a resistor of about 330 ohm in series with the button. Otherwise accidentally pressing the button when it is in UART mode will cause a short.

(Edit: sorry the formatting is a bit messed up, I cannot get the line breaks to display properly, I get either a double break or none at all)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, one good solution can be found here:

https://dr-mntn.net/2021/02/using-the-sd-card-in-1-bit-mode-on-the-esp32-cam-from-ai-thinker

or here (look for alanesq answer):

https://esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=13141

I also have trouble using GPIO 16 as input maybe because there is a pullup resistor connected to it.

The main idea is to use GPIO 12 and 13 (and also possibly the GPIO 4) by putting the SD card in “one bit mode”:

```
SD_MMC.begin("/sdcard", true);
```

Only after that step (otherwise, the initialization of the SD card would re-configure the GPIO pins again), one may define GPIO 12, 13 or 4 depending on its needs (OUTPUT, INPUT, INPUT_PULLUP) .

Note that GPIO 12 MUST be LOW at boot. In the following code, I added a little delay (10ms) to ensure that this condition is met when digitalreading the state.

I personally use GPIO 13 with a PIR and GPIO 12 with a switch (to read the state of the switch).

Here is the important part of my code:

```
  const int GPIO_SWITCH = 12;
  const int GPIO_PIR = 13;

  // Serial.println("Starting SD Card");
  if (!SD_MMC.begin("/sdcard", true))
  {
    Serial.println("SD Card Mount Failed");
    return;
  }

  // this two lines have to be after the SD_MMC.begin call
  pinMode(GPIO_PIR, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(GPIO_SWITCH, INPUT_PULLUP);

  delay(10); // Important delay for GPIO12 that need to be 0 at the beginning 


  int GPIO_12 = digitalRead(GPIO_SWITCH);

  if (GPIO_12 == 1)
  {
    Serial.println("Swith is OFF");
  }
```

With this code, I also have sometimes a bug with the following error :
"failed to initialize the card (263). make sure sd card lines have pull-up resistors in place."

This error appears because GPIO 13 is connected to a PIR sensor that maintain its states to LOW (0 V). But the problem is that when executing the function SD_MMC.begin("/sdcard", true), the esp32-CAM expects the GPIO 13 to be HIGH (3.3V). I did not found a software solution to solve this problem. I add a switch that allows me to force GPIO 13 to be HIGH when booting the esp32-CAM (to unconnect from the data line of the PIR). Once booted, I switch on the data line of the PIR and every thing works fine.